# Passing Control Id from Linkbutton in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I pass the Control ID in a gridview that is derived from a stored procedure into a variable. I will use the variable to pass into the database later on to return some results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var controlId = ((LinkButton)gridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lbName")).Id;
```

Are you trying to do something like the above?

Update 
You can use the OnSelectedIndex event of the GridView to find the row that was select.

```
  void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;

    var controlId = ((LinkButton)row.FindControl("lbName")).Id;
  }
```

Comment: this wont work. you have to find the GridViewRow, then find the linkbutton inside the row

Comment: @Jeff, oops, sorry forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: How would I write your scenario jeff?

Comment: @jpavlov, when are you trying to store the ControlId in a variable?

Comment: Should I write my linkbutton for the asp.net like this?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="ID" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                    SortExpression="ID" />

Comment: You've lost me, I thought you were trying to get the LinkButton Id from the GridView.

Comment: @jpavlov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1234/discussion-between-jethro-and-jpavlov)

Comment: I have this in my PageLoad
        string controlId = (gv2.Rows[0].FindControl("lnkID")).ID;
        lblshow.Text = control(lnkID);

Comment: and this is in my .aspx page
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkID" runat="server"
Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>

Comment: But when i run it, it shows in the label not the actual ID but "lnkID. How should I return the value?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the CommandName and CommandArgument fields with LinkButtons in a GridView.

The CommandName represents the name of the command, so that you can have more than one linkbutton that do different things and the CommandArgument is the Database ID or other point of reference for the command.

You need to subscribe to the RowCommand event handler on the GridView