# Passing an id value to LinkButton server side event in gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I am trying to pass a CustomerID value to codebehind, from my LinkButton in my gridview control.  I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614803/passing-control-id-from-linkbutton-in-a-gridview) but it does not work.

My gridview  code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name, First Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton OnClick="EditCustomer" id="lbtnCustomerName" CommandName="CustomerName" Visible="true" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to edit customer."><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custLastName") + ", " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custFirstName" + ", " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custID")%></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected void EditCustomer(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can I get the custID value in the EditCustomer event?

Comment: Wouldn't it simply be `sender.id`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Youc an pass the `CustomerID` as [`CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx):

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="EditCustomer" id="lbtnCustomerName" 
     CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>'
     CommandName="CustomerName"
     OnCommand="LinkButton_Command"
     Visible="true" runat="server"
     ToolTip="Click to edit customer."><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custLastName") + ", " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custFirstName" + ", " + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custID")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Now you can handle the LinkButton's [`Command` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.command):

```
void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
   String CustomerID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. How would the code behind appear? I am getting an error "No overload for 'EditCustomer' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' "

Comment: @DotNetRookie: Edited my answer to show how you handle the LinkButton's Command event.